# Git command to get authors of lines that I have changed

Tags: git

Let's say I changed 2 lines, the author of one line was *user1* and the author of the other line was *user2*. If I commit the changes my user will become the new author of these 2 lines. Now, do we have the possibility (using git command) to see that my commit modified 2 lines and that the previous authors of them were *user1* and *user2*?

I would like to use these users as reviewers for my changes. Maybe there are other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`git blame filename.txt` will show you authors of each line in current version,

`git blame HEAD~1 -- filename.txt` will show you authors of each line before the last commit,

`git blame <ref> -- filename.txt` will show you authors of each line at revision specified by `<ref>`.

`~1` is a *modifier* allowing you to say *1st parent of…*.